# Clear Stockfish hash table after every move conveniently

Tags: engines, stockfish, arena

When analyzing a game with Stockfish I sometimes find it confusing that evaluation of a given position changes depending on what positions I had analyzed previously. I understand that this is because the engine reuses its hash table contents. I'd rather have potentially weaker analysis but consistency.

Stockfish offers the `Clear Hash` UCI option which shows up as a button in the "configure engine" GUI of Arena.

Is there a way I can automatically clear the hash table whenever I switch positions?

Comment: Just change the source code it’s easy